# Why does customize buffer display "[ State ]: UNKNOWN, you should not see this"?

Tags: customize, defcustom

In a package of my own, namely `skel-el`, I  define a user option `skel-el-line1` (well, ok, I'm the only one user) which can be a string, a variable (containing some string) or a function (whithout parameter, returning a string). The default value
is a function:

```el
(defcustom skel-el-line1 (lambda ()
                           (concat skel-el-comment-title ...))
  "Blah blah."
  :set 'fset
  :group 'skel-el
  :type '(radio (string) (variable) (function)))
```

Everything works like a charm, except the customize buffer:

```
▼ Skel El Line1:
Choice:
( ) String: 
(*) Variable: nil
( ) Function: ignore
   [ State ]: UNKNOWN, you should not see this.
   Blah blah.
```

I suspect that the problem comes from the fact I didn't specify the `:get` keyword, but all my attempts to define it failed to fix the customize buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not setting the value of the user option at all.

You've specified `:set 'fset` which is going to make it set the value of the *function slot* of the symbol.  The user option (variable) value isn't touched, so if it hasn't otherwise been defined as a variable it remains void -- and Customize doesn't like that at all.

Experimentally, if you both:

- Set an appropriate `:get` -- in your case it would be `'symbol-function`
- Declare the symbol as a variable -- E.g. `(defvar skel-el-line1 nil)`

Then the interface works (based on absolute minimal testing, so YMMV).

I'm struggling to imagine that you actually want `fset`, though.

Comment: The two (bad) reasons for which I added `fset` are : (i) I thought it was necessary when the default value for `defcustom` is a function (ii) without it, the code using `skel-el-line1` was not functional. Thank you for your answer which clarifies my understanding of several key concepts (symbol cells, function, variable and user options), and incidentally excavates a hidden bug in my code.

Comment: You're welcome.  It sounds like you had `(skel-el-line1)` but wanted `(funcall skel-el-line1)`?  Have a read of `C-h i g (elisp)Calling Functions` if you haven't already.  To add some more related jargon, Emacs Lisp is a so-called Lisp-2 where the "2" means that variables and functions are in *two* separate name-spaces, rather than both sharing *one* name-space (as in a Lisp-1 like Scheme); hence in elisp we can have variables and functions with identical names, and so we need `funcall` and friends to call function values that are stored in variables.

Comment: Causing `fset` to be called for one of the *non-function* possibilities for your user option value would definitely have been weird :)

Comment: Yes, I've removed `fset` from my `defcustom` and `funcall` does the job when `skel-el-line1` is a function.